# Difference between Redirect::to() and View::make()

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have a blade form that posts to Controller, the controller then will redirect to the same URL after performing some operations.

Before redirecting to the user, two variables will be passed. My problem is that when using `Redirect::to()` only the `->with('item_list',$item_list)` is made available for the view, while `->with('added_items',$added_items)` when using the `$added_items` variable in the view gives me the error:

> ErrorException
>
> Undefined variable: added_items (View: /var/www/mw/app/views/delivery-> 
>   requests/create.blade.php)

Controller

```
if (Input::has('addItem')) 
        {
            if (Session::has('added-items')) 
            {
                $id = Input::get('item_id');

                $new_item = Item::find($id);

                Session::push('added-items', [
                        'item_id' => $id,
                        'item_name' => $new_item->item_name,
                        'item_quantity' => Input::get('item_quantity')
                    ]);

                $array = Session::get('added-items');

                //move outside foreach loop because we don't want to reset it
                $total = array();

                foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
                {
                    $id = $value['item_id'];
                    $quantity = $value['item_quantity'];

                    if (!isset($total[$id])) 
                    {
                        $total[$id] = 0;
                    }

                    $total[$id] += $quantity;
                }

                $items = array();

                foreach($total as $item_id => $item_quantity) 
                {
                    $new_item = Item::find($item_id);
                    $items[] = array(
                        'item_id' => $item_id,
                        'item_name' => $new_item->item_name,
                        'item_quantity' => $item_quantity
                        );
                }

                Session::put('added-items', $items);
            } 
            else 
            {
                $id = Input::get('item_id');
                $new_item = Item::find($id);

                Session::put('added-items', [
                    0 => [
                    'item_id'       => $id,
                    'item_name'     => $new_item->item_name,
                    'item_quantity' => Input::get('item_quantity')
                    ]
                ]);     
            }

            // pass the items again to the page
            $item_list = Item::lists('item_name', 'id');
            $added_items = Session::get('added-items');

            return View::make('delivery-requests/create')
                    ->with('added_items',$added_items)
                    ->with('item_list', $item_list);
        }
```

The reason I used `Redirect::to()` is that it maintains the same URL which is /delivery-requests/create

But when I use `View::make()` I can access the `$added_items` variable just fine, but the URL now becomes /delivery-requests , even if I explicitly put it like this:

```
return View::make('delivery-requests/create')
->with('added_items',$added_items)
->with('item_list', $item_list);
```

My question is why can't Redirect::to() read the $added_items variable on the view

Comment: Can you show us the controller's method code?

Comment: `Redirect::to()` returns a `RedirectResponse`.  The `with()` method within that class flashes the data you give it to the session, so you can probably try using `Session::get('added_items')` instead.

Comment: @fmgonzalez I have updated my question with the controller's method code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting to the route, return the method which is at the end of that route with any additional variables you need.

`return $this->create()->with('added_items', $added_items)->with('item_list', $item_list)` where `create()` is the method which is being used on the route `delivery-requests/create`.

Redirect is probably what you are actually after then,

`Redirect::to()->with('item_list', $item_list);`

Comment: I put the `return $this->create()->with('added_items', $added_items)->with('item_list', $item_list)` as the return of the `store()` method, so basically it works again. I'm just wondering why the URL is `delivery-requests`